# Can I make a tastypie modelresource field read-only?

Tags: tastypie

I have a Tastypie ModelResource which gets its fields from a regular Django Model. I would like to make certain fields read-only on the Tastypie resource, even though they are writeable in the underlying model. Is this possible to accomplish in a simple way?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ModelResource, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    for f in getattr(self.Meta, 'read_onlys', []):
        self.fields[f].read_only = True
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I couldn't get the aforementioned 'hack' to work with the resource/schema that is generated by Tastypie, which is really what I'm after

Comment: Ooops. I got it work by changing read_only to readonly. My bad.

Comment: shouldn't the super call have your classname in it

Comment: tolomea: you're right. I've made this mistake before. I wish there was a simpler / shorter way to to call the superclass without using super(MyClass, self) or SuperClass.foo(self).

Comment: Wait for python 3, super will magically be smart about the calling class and instance. http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#super

Comment: It would be nice if this was added to Tastypie. I would rename 'read_onlys' to 'readonly_fields' though.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I would do that sort of thing in the hydrate/dehydrate process.

There are probably other ways,

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):
    if bundle.obj.pk:
        bundle.data['somefield'] = bundle.obj.somefield
    else:
        bundle.data.pop('somefield', None)  # no KeyError if 'somefield' missing

    return super(MyResource, self).hydrate(bundle)
```

Comment: You're right, but I forgot to mention that I wanted the schema that Tastypie can output for the resource to refelect that it was readonly. My 'solution' does this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [BaseModelForm overwrites self.instance when doing validation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.1/django/forms/models.py#L396).

And this ofcourse happens regardless if a Tastypie field has `readonly` set or not (that onfly affects Tastypie's own `hydrate`, nothing else).

So I ended up writing this: https://gist.github.com/thnee/8522224

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you need this anymore, but here's the link to official documentation related to [readonly](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#readonly) fields.

**example:**

```
class ResourceA(ModelResource):
    read_only_field = fields.DateTimeField('attribute', readonly=True)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks